# How to use two fields in body for methos put in retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have two strings that I should set them in body for my put request. How can do it with retrofit?

```
@PUT("/user-management/Account/activate")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json"})
    Call<Verification> activation(@Part("code") String code , @Part("token") String token);
```

Comment: without proper context no one will be able to answer your question.

Comment: `@PUT("/user-management/Account/activate")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json"})
    Call<Verification> activation(@Part("code") String code , @Part("token") String token);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try similar code I posted below: For detailed code please post your context or a part of your code.

```
@Multipart    
@PUT("user/photo")
Call<User> updateUser(@Part("photo") RequestBody photo, @Part("description") RequestBody description);
```

Comment: I try it but unfortunately i got this err: `@Part parameters can only be used with multipart encoding. (parameter #1).` I also used `@FormUrlEncoded
    @Headers({ "Content-Type: application/json"})` too but its not working

Comment: Edited the answer. try again

Answer (score 0):

You can pass multiple Strings in Body like this:

Create a Class

```
public class Verification
{
    public String code;
    public String token;
}
```

Set the data to object

```
Verification loginCredentials = new Verification();
loginCredentials.code= "12345;
loginCredentials.token= "54321";
```

Call your api

```
@PUT("/user-management/Account/activate")
 Call<Verification> activation(@Body Verificationcredentials);
```